# Use variables in symbolic expressions - matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

How can I use variables inside a symbolic variable in Matlab?

For example, I have the following code:

```
function f = constr_fourier(vec);
dim=prod(size(vec));
n=(dim-1)/2;
a=@(k) vec(k+1);
b=@(k) vec(n+k-1);

f = @(x) subs(a,{k,0})/2 + symsum(subs(a,{k,i})*cos(i*x) + ...
subs(b,{k,i})*sin(i*x),i,1,n);
```

In which I want to recover the Fourier series given a vector of coefficients `vec`. I want to replace the actual values from vec into the symbolic expression of the function. I tried that with `subs` but it doesn't work, or I didn't use it right.

What is the right way to do this?

[edit] I have tried

```
f = @(x) subs(a,k,0)/2 + symsum(subs(a,k,i)*cos(i*x) + ...
subs(b,{k,i})*sin(i*x),i,1,n);
```

but the result is with `subs(...)` and not with the numerical value of `a(k)`.

I have tried also a different variant, which gives the a result but in a wrong way...

```
function f = constr_fourier(w);
syms x k n u c t vector;

evalin(symengine,'assume(k,Type::Integer)');

dim=prod(size(w));
m=(dim-1)/2;

a0=w(1);
a= w(2:m+1);
b= w(m+2:2*m+1);

u=@(k,vector) vector(k);

fs = @(x,n,c) c/2 + symsum(subs(u,{k,vector},{t,a})*cos(t*x) + subs(u,{k,vector},          {t,b})*sin(t*x),t,1,n);

f= fs(x,m,a0);
```

I tried to use the function `u=@(k,vec) vec(k)` instead of the initial one. When I use `subs(u,{k,vector},{t,a})` separately in the terminal, it works ok, but here it doesn't...

I get the result as a vector of two function instead of a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) is indeed the right way, you're just using it wrong.

There are three input arguments for `subs`: the symbolic expression, the parameters to substitute and their new value. There is one exception though: if there are two input arguments, `subs` replaces the *default* symbolic parameter in the expression with the second argument.

Anyway, it seems that you're missing the new values in `subs`, so it doesn't behave like you meant it to. I think that it is supposed to look like this:

```
subs(a, k, 0)
```

etc...

As a side note, it is sufficient (and more elegant) to use `subs` only once. Compute your *entire* symbolic expression and then use `subs` once. So instead of:

```
subs(a, ...) + subs(b, ...)
```

I recommended you to do this instead:

```
subs(a + b, ...)
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. The result is given in symbolic form with `subs` still there. The variables are not replaced with their numerical values...

Comment: @BeniBogosel it would help if you post in your question what you have tried, so that I can see what when wrong.

Comment: I gave up the approach... subs kept making a 2x1 vector result, which I could not understand. Everything ran fine separately, but the symsum didn't work. I made a vector of sin(kx), a vector of cos(kx) and solved it with two scalar products. Thank you for your help though. :)

Comment: @BeniBogosel Your problem is that `symsum` also returns a symbolic expression. You should've computed `a + b + symsum(...)` first, and then use `subs` just once. Anyway, I don't like symbolic math either -- it is surely not the most efficient way to solve equations, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
a=@(k) vec(k+1);
```

then `a` is not a symbolic expression, but a *function,* and to get a specific value for `k` into that, you cannot use `subs`. Instead, you have to *call* the function `a`:

```
a(1)

f = @(x) a(0)/2 + sum(@(i) a(i)*cos(i*x) + b(i)*sin(i*x),1,n)
```